# Cron job is running but not updating Inventory

Tags: cron, csv, magento-cron, cronjobs

I am using mass product import and export Extension from Wyomind
https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/mass-product-update-import-magento.html

I have scheduled tasks to run csv profile after every 30 minutes
[image: Scheduled tasks]

I have checked the Inventory is not updated what should be done???

Comment: Did you try executing indexing?

Comment: What it has to do with reindexing?

Comment: please check CRON log i.e `cron.log`,`update.cron.log` and `update.log` etc..

Comment: Cron Job cronscheduler_heartbeat is missed                                                                                         at 2020-11-27 12:18:00 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Cron Job cron                                                                                        scheduler_heartbeat is missed at 2020-11-27 12:18:00 at app/code/Wyomind/CronScheduler/Plugin/Cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueO                                                                                        bserver.php:353)"} []